# Refactoring from Fragments to Activities

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is a bit of a desperation call for some good advice.

I began doing a project which involves Navigation drawer as the main menu for the application. After looking at the [Android tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) I followed the example and start developing on top of that. That example is a single activity that replaces the fragments depending on the selected option in the drawer. In part, I followed this design because if I launched Activities the drawer was lost and the Activity would appear with the launching transition and didn't look nice at all.

Now, my project is not a small one. During development I faced several issues like:

- onResume not being called on the Fragments (due to not being attached to several activities but one instead.
- All the data between Fragments should pass through the single Activity
- Managing the Options Menus in the ActionBar became a real pain.
- And many others I don't recall now

Now I am facing a new issue. In one of the fragments I need to have a Spinner that will switch fragments inside this one. And of course, the fragment will need to change the navigation mode in the action bar. This was a major headache to develop, but now I am facing a bigger problem with some fragments inside losing the activity context (like if they were detached).

After so many problems I just decided to switch back the whole app to Activities (this is a custom app that will run in just 1 tablet model, so no worries about fragmentation). So, in short I am looking for advice on the less painful way to do this.

I am on a extremely tight deadline that lead me to start implementing without designing (like a complete noob). Now I am being hit with so many issues that, if I didn't need the money, I would cancel this project at once.

Please help!

Comment: How did everything go?  I recently tried to change my app's architecture to a single activity, but I am starting to think that was a bad idea.

Comment: I somehow managed to keep the project with a single activity and one fragment per each screen. I wouldn't recommend anyone to do that, there are so many features that relate heavily on the Activity that is really hacky to get things to work. If your application is not too advanced in development I would tell you to keep 1 Activity per Fragment. As @Shadesblade said, it should be easy to do if, unlike me, the app is not almost finished with plenty of hacky workarounds already in place. Good luck ;-)

Comment: Thanks so much for your input!  I think I will switch back to activities.  It kind of bothers me that the navigation drawer seems to push for loading fragments in, but then dealing in just fragments is so difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give a little advice, but sadly your situation can't really be solved by any one answer here.

First off, switching from a Fragment design to an Activity design is a lot easier than switching the opposite way. You can actually use all of the fragments you had before, and just have each activity loading only 1 of the fragments (or multiple if you prefer).

Also, when handling Intents (starting new activity), after the `startActivity()` call you can call `overridePendingTransition()` to make the launching transition whatever you want (or remove it completely).

Comment: Thanks! I guess it was more like a desperate ranting than anything else. Anyway your answer made me feel more positive about refactoring the whole thing, it should not be that hard except for all the hacky workarounds I have in place to overcome this "design" limitations.